Login Password Doesn't Work for sudo Command
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS n a Dell Precision T1700, 64-bit. Since installation (about 2 years ago) the root PW has not been changed, and works for login. For the first 6 to 9 months it worked for sudo commands but since then has not. (Terminal image attached.)
Since this started happening, I did a reset of the root PW (using same original PW) but nothing changed with the sudo commands.
Are there any solutions short of reinstalling the OS and starting fresh or going with a different distro.


Only one password has ever been given under this installation, so any password for tim would be the same as for the root, which should also be the same for sudo., as I understand it.

cap locks on?  num-locks on?  Before you try again - simply type the correct password on the command line as if it were a command - so that you can see what you typed.

I did that and was typing what intended. Repeated it on the password line and even tried copying and pasting the password that I typed in the password line. Still, "Sorry, try again."

A sudo command uses the issuing ID's password, which may not necessarily be the same as root's password.  In this example,  the password which should be give would be the one for the ID tim.
